# Windows Communications Foundation Simple Beginning

Tags: wcf

Does anyone know of some (very) simple tutorials on line on the WCF?

Basically I need to play catch up and would like to start with a very basic sample so that i can get some good ground work in place before moving on to more advanced topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here:

[What is WCF?](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-What_is_WCF.aspx)

[Writing the WCF Hello World App (service)](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Writing_the_WCF_Hello_World_App.aspx)

[Writing your first WCF (client)](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Writing_your_first_WCF_client.aspx)

Very simple as you want...

Comment: +1, Blocked by our WebSense but will check it out from home tonight thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because I am lazy and would rather have someone tell me about WCF while I could see their code, I liked these screencasts.

1) [Beginner's Guide to Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx)

2) [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) Screencasts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-screencasts.aspx)

Comment: +1 How much do I love screen casts like dnrtv?  Thanks for this one.